# removing Action column selection from column selection Extjs

Tags: extjs, action, gridpane

how to hide or remove action column from column selection :
please check image for more idea.

[image]

Comment: try setting `hideable:false` config in column. refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-hideable)

Comment: work in other column but not work in action column

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3prq/45/

Comment: check update in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3prq/46/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {
  xtype: 'actioncolumn',
  hideable:false,
  width: 50,
  items: [{...}]
}
```

add hideable in actioncolum config